# How to add letters to result data

Tags: sql, oracle

when I run following query,

```
select
 NVL(week, 'SUM) week
  , sum(A) AS A, sum(B) AS B
from
  (
  select b.* 
     from TABLE  b
    where b.week between '2013051' and '2013052'
  )
 group by ROLLUP(WEEK)
```

I get data like

```
   |  WEEK  | 

    2013051

    2013052
```

But I want the data to be named as below.

```
   |  WEEK  | 

2013. 05. 1 WEEK 

2013. 05. 2 WEEK
```

Can anyone help me fixing this?

Comment: You don't need to put `<SQL>` in the title of all your questions; you're tagging them with [SQL] anyway, so it is just noise, and makes the title a bit harder to read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `week` is a string:

```
select substr(week, 1, 4)
    ||'. '|| substr(week, 5, 2)
    ||'. '|| substr(week, 7, 1) ||' WEEK' as week,
...
```

Or if `week` can be null (which it can't from your data because of your subquery's filter, but you get a generated null value from your `rollup` which I initially missed):

```
select case when week is null then 'SUM'
    else substr(week, 1, 4)
        ||'. '|| substr(week, 5, 2)
        ||'. '|| substr(week, 7, 1) ||' WEEK' end as week,
...

WEEK                      A          B
---------------- ---------- ----------
2013. 05. 1 WEEK          1          2 
2013. 05. 2 WEEK          3          4 
SUM                       4          6
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1774e/1); and one [without the subquery](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1774e/2), which seems superfluous here.

Answer (score 1):

If your Oracle RDBMS version is 10g or higher, the [regexp_replace](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm) function can be used to do a custom string formatting, as well:

```
select regexp_replace( 
         week, -- if week is of varchar2 datatype or to_char(week) if it's of number datatype
         '^([[:digit:]]{4})([[:digit:]]{2})([[:digit:]]{1})$', '\1. \2. \3  WEEK'
       )
  from your_table_name_or_subquery
```

result:

```
WEEK    
------------------
2013. 05. 1 WEEK 
2013. 05. 2 WEEK
```